# How can I not have notices logged in apache error log?

Tags: apache-2.4, log-files

On a regular basis I am tasked with going through the Apache error log. I would really only like to see things that are an actual issue.

In my httpd.conf file, I have `LogLevel warn`. I have done a grep on the system to find any other places where it might be set differently, but they are all at the warn level.

The following "errors" are being logged repeatedly and it makes it hard to find actual issues.

```
[Sun Jan 21 03:37:07.686531 2018] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 1109] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Jan 21 03:37:07.713539 2018] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 1109] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Sun Jan 21 03:37:09.575654 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1109] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips PHP/5.6.33 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jan 21 03:37:09.575677 2018] [core:notice] [pid 1109] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Mon Jan 22 09:34:42.928196 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1109] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Mon Jan 22 09:37:56.685298 2018] [suexec:notice] [pid 1127] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
```

Comment: That's odd. Only things I can suggest are to use [mod_info](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_info.html) to check that the LogLevel is what you expect, and use grep -v ':notice' on the log.

Comment: Starting/Stopping entries are always logged even if they are notice, those are rare occurance since they just happen when sarting or stopping so unless you are constantly restarting the server they don't show up. LogLevel warn affects normal behaviour not starting stopping errors. If you want to differentiate create error logs for each of your virtualhosts and leave "error log" for core error logging. Also if you have to navigate those logs what prevents you from doing "grep -v notice error.log"?